# multiset<Type*>::find почему-то находит элементы с аргументом в виде только что созданного указателя

Tags: c++, указатели, stl, итераторы, multiset

Разбираю старый код. Имеется контейнер std::multiset с указателями на структуру. Далее по коду после создания каждого указателя на структуру и заполнения её полей проверяется, нет ли в контейнере такого же указателя... Я считал, что такой код не нёс никакой смысловой нагрузки:

```
    //Комменты на англ. писал не я
    string16 header; // typedef char string16 [16];
    str_value* sv = (str_value*)header; //str_value - та структура, на которую хранятся указатели
    sv->dwReference = 0;
    sv->dwLength = s_len;
    sv->dwCRC = crc32(value,s_len); //Вычисление контрольной суммы, как я понял, уникальный идентификатор

    //template <typename K, class P=std::less<K>, typename allocator = xalloc<K> > class xr_multiset : public std::multiset<K,P,allocator> {public: u32 size() const {return (u32)__super::size();}};
    //typedef xr_multiset<str_value*,str_value_cmp> cdb;
    //cdb container;
    cdb::iterator I = container.find(sv); // only integer compares :)
    if (I!=container.end())
    {
        // something found - verify, it is exactly our string
        // Детали не важны
    }
```

Казалось бы, как в контейнере можно найти совпадение с только что созданным указателем `sv`? Даже если у структуры по этому указателю целиком совпадают поля с некой структурой по находящемуся в контейнере указателю, у них адреса разные! Это разные объекты, и find никогда не должен срабатывать. **Но нет, точка останова постоянно срабатывает внутри** `if (I!=container.end())`. Ну я почитал, как сравниваются указатели (как я и знал, они равны, только если являются нулевыми или ссылаются на одно и то же), почитал, как работает multiset::find (простое сравнение аргумента с элементами, в данном случае указатель с указателями, и подозрение на функцию сравнения `str_value_cmp` отпало), и до сих пор ума не приложу, как это работает. Смысл комментария в коде

> // only integer compares :)

я считал заблуждением, а теперь считаю магией. Помогите разобраться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, на то и **мульти**множество, что оно может содержать одинаковые элементы!

А во-вторых, сравниваются значения с помощью *компаратора*, а как работает ваш компаратор `str_value_cmp`, из вопроса не ясно — а ведь он вполне может смотреть на содержимое структуры!

Кстати, ориентируясь на комментарий *only integer compares :)*, можно заключить, что он сравнивает только какое-то целочисленное поле структуры, т.е. никак не значения указателей, а значения в структурах, на которые они указывают.

Answer (score 0):

К моему превеликому удивлению дело оказалось действительно в компараторе, [Harry](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/195342/harry) в этом был прав. Обнаружил это, добавив в код компаратора вывод в консоль ключевой информации. Ни в документации Microsoft, ни на cppreference не нашёл никакого упоминания о том, что компаратор, используемый, казалось бы, только для упорядочивания элементов в контейнере, влияет на поведение компонентных функций.

---

*Правда не понимаю, за что минусуют, вопрос-то касается максимально неочевидного нюанса, который запросто заставит потратить на отладку несколько часов как минимум*

Comment: *за что минусуют* — Ну, в конце концов, мне тоже никто плюс не поставил, несмотря на правильный ответ :), а даже наоборот — заминусовал... Как никто его и не принял.

Comment: @Harry,  я поставил) Только голос не учитывается из-за рейтинга

Comment: Я намекал, что если ответ вас устроил — его можно и принять (птичка слева от ответа).

Comment: @Harry, пытаюсь восстановить справедливость и поставить плюс :)